# Is there an easier way to join multiple tables/views with the same criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data that’s split across multiple view and I use the same keys to join them like so:

```
Select t1.ID, t1.Date, t1.var1, t2.var2, t3.var3, t4.var4
From table1 as t1

Left join table2 as t2
On (t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Date = t2.Date)

Left join table3 as t3
On (t1.ID= t3.ID and t1.Date = t3.Date)

…
```

Is there a way to simplify the join clauses since all of them are being joined on the same keys?

Comment: You are joining across individual tables, so each one will require its own `ON` definition. In short, no.

Comment: In standard SQL you'd use `left join table2 t2 using (id, date)`, but SQL Server doesn't support this syntax. So, no, you can't simplify the join clauses. (It's weird anyway that you join on the ID being the same, but that's probably just the example you made up here.)

Comment: That’s too bad… Thanks for the responses!

Comment: When you say "split" do you mean normalized, or just separated?

Comment: You could simplify the writing of the query with some dynamic SQL, but ultimately, no, the SQL text executed would be the same